# How to make div's height equal to the width

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs  with `display:inline-block`. Each div set width to 30%, and height to 75%. The problem is that the width is bigger than the height and i want it to be the same (1:1). Can I solve it only by CSS?

```css
#our_services {
    height: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular", arial, "Times New Roman";
    color: black;
    background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
    overflow: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
#try {
    background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
    width:60%;
    height:70%;
    margin:auto;
}
#product1 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 75%;
    position: relative;
    background-color:green;
    display:inline-block;
    /* margin:5px; */
    border: 0px;
}
#product2 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 75%;
    background-color:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    /* margin:5px; */
    border: 0px;
}
#product3 {
    width: 30%;
    height: 75%;
    background-color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    /* margin:5px; */
}
```

```html
<div id="our_services" class="container">
    <h1></h1>
    <div id="try">
        <div id="product1"></div>
        <div id="product2"></div>
        <div id="product3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS maintain div aspect ratio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/css-maintain-div-aspect-ratio)

Comment: for this to work you parent element would have to be the same height and width since that is what the percentage value for the child elements relate to

Answer (score 1):

try this.keep same size for width and height.

```
#try{
background-color: rgb(224,224,224);
width:60%;
height:60%;
margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the ratio (1:1) as square, try to use the css tricks:

```css
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.square {
  width: 33%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
  float: left;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="square red"></div>
  <div class="square blue"></div>
  <div class="square green"></div>
</div>
```

Set height to 0 and width and padding-bottom to the same values.